# Android - Take picture API 23

Tags: android

I'm using this code to take a picture on Android and get the path and it works fine on my Android device API 17.

This is the intent

```
//Open camera
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

//start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

And here, I get the path

```
String picturePath;
Uri selectedImage;
Bitmap photo;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        try 
          {
              selectedImage = data.getData();
              String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
              cursor.moveToFirst();

              int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
              picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

             //I got the picturePath, i m going to pass it to a method..
             createUploadFile();
             String check = uploadFile.execute(picturePath).get();

             cursor.close();
       ....
```

The problem is on API 24, or more, `onActivityResult` Intent data local variable is null and i get error here.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

I have added the runtime android permission.

Any helps? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using this code to take a picture on Android and get the path and it works fine on my Android device API 17.

It will not work for most devices and most camera apps, though. `data.getData()` is supposed to return `null` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, insofar as [it is not documented to return anything](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

*Your* bug is in calling `data.getData()` in the first place. You know where the image is supposed to be located: in the location you provided to `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (in this case, whatever `fileUri` is). So, look there for your image, and get rid of the unnecessary `query()` call.